# Rails - pass a parameter to a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I have following situation:

In the application there are clients and projects. A client can have many projects and a project belongs to a client. I've created everything with scaffolding and the relationship works. I can create a project with reference on a client.

But now i would like to create a button in the view of a client, which links to the "New Project Form" and pass the current client as param. Due to that the client should be pre set in the form for the new Project.

I tried to do this by passing the param as following:

```
<%= link_to "New Project", new_project_path(:project => { :client_id => @client.id } ), :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

But I don't get it how i now could use the param :client_id in the new project form. Or may be there is a other way to do this directly in the project controller.

Thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a [nested resource](http://railscasts.com/episodes/139-nested-resources) perhaps with [polymorphic association](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association-revised?autoplay=true) setup. This way you don't need to pass the client_id. Researching the two topics should help a lot.

Here is what I use with simple form to hide the dropdown if a client is set. The rest is Rails magic if you set up your relationships properly.

```
<% unless @client %>
  <%= f.association :client, prompt: 'Select a client...', label_method: lambda { |client| "#{client.first_name} #{client.middle_name} #{client.last_name}" } %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks! watched the screencast about nested resource and implemented it right away :)

Comment: Glad you found what you were looking for!